# Office 2016/19 Click2Run vs MSI excel performance

Tags: microsoft-office

is there any difference in performance (big excel files) between different versions of Office? There is Click2Run and MSI base installations.

I think there is no difference but still want to ask.

Comment: I also think there is no performance difference between C2R versions and MSI versions of Excel. The difference between two installation technology is listed in [MSI vs Click To Run Office installations – How to switch](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/msi-vs-click-to-run-office). Generally, hardware ,environment and bit editions determine Excel performance. For More information, read [Excel performance: Performance and limit improvements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-performance-and-limit-improvements).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.

These are different ways of delivering (installing) the SAME software.